# Maximum and minimum numbers of comparisons for heap sort

Tags: java, sorting, heapsort

When N=32,How to find arrays of items that make heapsort use as many and as few comparisons as possible?

```
Does it mean O(N log N) (minimum comparisons) and O(N square) for maximum comparisons.
```

Am i doing correct?

Comment: Are you sure you are talking about Heapsort? For both worse and best cases, Heapsort have runtime complexity of O(nlogn).

Comment: @Trein, yes i am talking about heapsort. How to find the array of items?

Comment: Take a look at http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1540/finding-a-worst-case-of-heap-sort. It describes how to find the worst case combination.

Comment: take a look at these links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22214495/find-a-heapified-array-when-converting-it-to-a-sorted-array-the-total-number-of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22017852/heapsort-input-with-most-and-fewest-comparisons

Comment: @Trein since that [question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1540/finding-a-worst-case-of-heap-sort) have no accurate answer, I post a Q&A on so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22214495/find-a-heapified-array-when-converting-it-to-a-sorted-array-the-total-number-of