# heapsort input with most and fewest comparisons

Tags: algorithm, sorting, heapsort

Hi I've looked around a bit and haven't been able to find any direct discussion of this question. Most seem to cover time complexity and the big O notation.

I'm wondering if and how the order of input into a heapsort algorithm will impact the number of comparisons needed to sort the input. For example, take a heapsort algorithm that sorts in ascending order (smallest to largest)....if I input a set of integers already ordered in this way (ascending) how many comparisons would it require compared to a set of input that is ordered in a descending manner (largest to smallest)? How about compared to a completely randomized set of the same numbers?

```
public class Heap {
    // This class should not be instantiated.
    private Heap() {
    }

    /**
     * Rearranges the array in ascending order, using the natural order.
     * 
     * @param pq
     *            the array to be sorted
     */
    public static void sort(Comparable[] pq) {
        int N = pq.length;
        for (int k = N / 2; k >= 1; k--)
            sink(pq, k, N);
        while (N > 1) {
            exch(pq, 1, N--);
            sink(pq, 1, N);
        }
    }

    private static void sink(Comparable[] pq, int k, int N) {
        while (2 * k <= N) {
            int j = 2 * k;
            if (j < N && less(pq, j, j + 1))
                j++;
            if (!less(pq, k, j))
                break;
            exch(pq, k, j);
            k = j;
        }
    }

    private static boolean less(Comparable[] pq, int i, int j) {
        return pq[i - 1].compareTo(pq[j - 1]) < 0;
    }

    private static void exch(Object[] pq, int i, int j) {
        Object swap = pq[i - 1];
        pq[i - 1] = pq[j - 1];
        pq[j - 1] = swap;
    }

    // is v < w ?
    private static boolean less(Comparable v, Comparable w) {
        return (v.compareTo(w) < 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heap sort is different from bubble sort and quick sort, the best and worst cases wouldn't happen when the input elements are ordered in a descending/ascending manner. The first step of heap sort is building a heap(max-heap in general) which can be done in linear time O(n) by using the "sift down" version of heapify, **no matter what order the initial elements are**. If the input is already a heap, it just saves the time for exchange.
It's generally considered the best and worst cases performance are both O(nlogn)(**[the heap sort item on wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort) says the best case performance can be Ω(n), and there's a link about it**), but the big-O notation omits **constant factors and lower order terms**, so they are equivalent in big O notation, but they can differ by a constant factor.

For example, I get all 720 permutations of a given elemnts:{1,2,3,4,5,6} and sort them with your code, the minimum/maximum number of comparisons is 12/17 while the order is {6,1,4,2,3,5}/{1,4,2,5,6,3} respectively. And the minimum/maximum number of exchanges is 8/15 while the order is {6,3,5,1,2,4}/{1,2,3,5,4,6} respectively. [My another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22214495/find-a-heapified-array-when-converting-it-to-a-sorted-array-the-total-number-of) is about the maximum number of exchanges.